# I want to read and write files on server how can I do it using command prompt

Tags: command-line

I want to read a particular file from server and after comparing them I want to write the difference in a txt file at the same server how can I do the same using command prompt.

```
findstr /vixlg:\\dmzintegration\data comparison upload\WebSourceExtractorDev\DispatchDirectory\Harvester2\109365_cc50f106-f362-4924-9db4-29412249da5b.txt \\dmzintegration\Data Comparison Upload\WebSourceExtractor\ExtractedPrior\109365_cc50f106-f362-4924-9db4-29412249da5b.txt>\\dmzintegration\Data Comparison Upload\WebSourceExtractor\ExtractedUnique\109365_cc50f106-f362-4924-9db4-29412249da5b.txt
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I compare two files using the command line?

Use `fc` to compare files.

Example:

```
fc a.txt b.txt > diff.txt
```

---

> **Syntax**
>
> FC /B pathname1 pathname2
>
> FC [options] pathname1 pathname2
>
> **Key**
>
> /B : Perform a binary comparison.
>
> **options**
>
> /C : Do a case insensitive string comparison
>
> /A : Displays only first and last lines for each set of differences.
>
> /U : Compare files as UNICODE text files.
>
> /L : Compares files as ASCII text. (default)
>
> /N : Display line numbers (ASCII only)
>
> /LBn : Limit the number of lines that will be read, "n" sets a maximum number of consecutive differing lines after which the File Comparison will abort (resync failed). When FC aborts then "n" number of mismatches will be shown. default=100 lines.
>
> /nnnn : Specify a number of consecutive lines that must match after a mismatch. This can be used to prevent the display of the two files from getting too out of sync
>
> /T : Do not expand tabs to spaces.
>
> /W : Compress white space (tabs and spaces) for comparison.

Source [fc](http://ss64.com/nt/fc.html)

---

#### How do I access file on a server from the command line?

Mount the network location as a network drive using `net use`.

Example:

```
net use x: "\\dmzintegration\data comparison upload"
```

Now you can refer to your files using:

```
x:\WebSourceExtractorDev\DispatchDirectory\Harvester2\109365_cc50f106-f362-4924-9db4-29412249da5b.txt 
x:\WebSourceExtractor\ExtractedPrior\109365_cc50f106-f362-4924-9db4-29412249da5b.txt
x:\WebSourceExtractor\ExtractedUnique\109365_cc50f106-f362-4924-9db4-29412249da5b.txt
```

---

```
Syntax

  NET USE [devicename | *] [\\computername\sharename[\volume] [password | *]]
          [/USER:[domainname\]username]
          [/USER:[dotted domain name\]username]
          [/USER:[username@dotted domain name]
          [/SMARTCARD] [/SAVECRED] [[/DELETE] | [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]]

Map to the current user's home directory as specified in the users
Active Directory record:

  NET USE {devicename | *} [password | *] /HOME

Set defaults:

  NET USE [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [fc](http://ss64.com/nt/fc.html) - Compare the contents of two files or sets of files. Display any lines which do NOT match.
- [net use](http://ss64.com/nt/net_use.html) - Map a drive letter to a remote server/share.

Comment: I am done with the comparison my question is how can I access a file from server and write the same file onto server

Comment: @Anoop Answer updated

Comment: This helps me.. Is there any command in which I can ignore writing text to a file if there is no result in the same script?

Comment: @Anoop Please edit your question to show the **exact** batch file you are currently using and some sample data for the files you are comparing.

Comment: @Anoop If you are stilll using `findstr` - "FINDSTR will set %ERRORLEVEL% as follows:

    0 (False) a match is found in at least one line of at least one file.
    1 (True) if a match is not found in any line of any file, (or if the file is not found at all)."